# Excel VBA Problem with Evaluate Function: returns just zeros

Tags: excel, evaluate

I have a Range with data. Every cell needs to be multiplied by 2. I’m using the code below. `last_row` is an int which is set to the last row of the document.

```
    Set rngData = res.Range("A5:C" & last_row)
    rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*2")
```

When I run the macro, the whole range is just zeros. But if I put a breakpoint at the evaluate row then it works perfectly fine. It seems that it runs too fast. When I "slow it down" by setting a breakpoint it works. Do you have an idea what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

So i fixed the Problem. If you have not activated the Worksheet you are working on you get the zeros. So in this case i put `res.activate` infront of the code

Comment: `rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address(External:=true) & "*2")` will work as well.